# Dynamic Case Statements in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, dynamic, case

How would I go about writing:

```
PreviousInput='@(User1 | User2 | User3)*#channel'
###############################
Expression="*${PreviousInput}*"
case $Input in
    $Expression ) 
        Do_Something ;;
    *)
        Do_Something_Else ;;
esac
```

I would really like to use a case statement because I have a lot of logic already invested in the case statement, and really don't want to rewrite it.  I was thinking that somehow I could use glob patterns, but don't really know how I would do that.  Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question to include sample data for ${PreviousInput}. Good luck!

Comment: Added, the PreviousInput string is dynamically generated, so the string will change, but that's a good sample.

Comment: And per your previous question on this topic, you are using `shopt -s extglob`? If you're lucky, you might be able to wrap the whole multi-line statmement with `eval` but requries a leading and a closing dbl-quote chars aroudn the whole thing. If you need to add dbl-quotes around your ${Expression} value, then you'll need to escape those, i.e. `\"${Expression\"`. So... `eval "case $Input in \"${Expression|\" ) ... ; esac "` . And escape your `*`. This approach can get hairy real fast. You'll have to spend time on understanding eval, order of evaluation for shell cmd line, etc. Good luck.

Comment: Is there a reason you put Expression in a variable?  Because without these indirections, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The bash manual says:

> Each pattern examined is expanded using tilde expansion, parameter and
>   variable expansion,  arithmetic substitution, command substitution,
>   and process substitution.

So I don't see any reason that your example shouldn't be exactly equivalent to

```
case $Input in
    *@(User1 | User2 | User3)*#channel* ) 
        Do_Something ;;
    *)
        Do_Something_Else ;;
esac
```

which should do what you want as long as you have `shopt -s extglob` set, as shellter says.